# Make ContainerView above navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I need to add slideout right viewController to another.

[image]

I tried to use Container View but it doesn't draw upper of navigationBar =( and my view, that I use for shadow also draw under naviationBar

Answer (score 0):

If you've done your containerView correctly, you can just add:

```
// Prevents overlapping of navigationbar
edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Bottom
```

This way the navigationBar will always be visible in your containerView.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a parent master view controller (without navigation bar).
- 1 container view that contains your viewcontroller with navigationbar/controller
- 1 container view that contains the viewcontroller that slides over the first one.

If you mean the bar with battery level and such by "upper of navigationBar", you're probably talking about the status bar.
You can hide this programmatically

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool
{
return true
}
```